# Id search in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Now i want to search id in field.

```
builder.startObject().startObject(TYPE_SERIES).startObject("properties");

    builder.startObject(ID)
            .field("type", "long")
            .field("store", "yes")
            .field("index", "analyzed")
            .field("analyzer", "test_analyzer")
            .endObject();

    builder.startObject(TITLE)
            .field("type", "string")
            .field("store", "yes")
            .field("index", "analyzed")
            .field("analyzer", "test_analyzer")
            .field("boost", "10")
            .endObject();
```

I tried to search ID like this:

```
.setQuery(QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(query, 
                       ID, TITLE))
```

BTW, I can get result with id, instead I cannot search with title. 
I just only search with id for getting results.

So I changed this like this. 
I used MultiSearchResponse so that I tried to execute two kids of queries.

One is

```
.setQuery(QueryBuilders.idsQuery(TYPE).ids(query))
```

the other is

```
.setQuery(QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(query, 
                                            TITLE,DESCRIPTION))
```

Unfortunately, I just get result with title or description. 
If I search for ID, i cannot get any results.

================
I'd like to execute like this

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/test/series/99
```

I want to get results with ID. Unfortunately, I don't know well how to make this code with JAVA API.

Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what you're searching for and what your documents look like. Also, check what the submitted mapping looks like using the get mapping api, just to make sure it is what you expect it to be.

Comment: I want to search title, id, description in the existing database table. Now I can search title, description with terms. But I have trouble to find id. When I add id field in multiMatchQuery, I can get result from id but I didn't have any results from other fields. This is my problem.

Comment: @Soo, could you provide a complete example that would be possible to run and see what's going on?

Answer (score 3):

There's a _id field that you can search in. So, curl `http://localhost:9200/_search?q=_id:99+AND+_type:series+AND+_index:test` or `http://localhost:9200/test/series/_search?q=_id:99` should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Like the previous people have said, a complete example would help. But let's say your document type you're looking for is "series":

```
.setQuery(QueryBuilders.idsQuery("series").addIds("99"));
```

Or a bit more complete:

```
SearchResponse esResponse = esClient.prepareSearch("test")
                .setQuery(QueryBuilders.idsQuery("series").addIds("99"))
                .execute().actionGet();
```